# Invisble checkbox in Arcana Template

Tags: html, css, templates

I use Arcana HTML5 Template from https://html5up.net/arcana and adopted the template to GetSimple CMS. Both templates (the original one and the one I have in CMS) don#t display  elements. Text is cisible, but not the checkbox itself.

I played a little bit around with css appearance für input[type="checkbox"], but no results. Maybe it's the wrong idea, or wrong position in code.

**Selection from original css**

```
@import url("fontawesome-all.min.css");
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/cssfamily=Source+Sans+Pro:300,300italic,600,600italic");

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5,
h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, 
code, del, fn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, 
strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, 
li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, 
thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, 
figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, 
section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

input, select, textarea {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
 }

body, input, select, textarea {
    color: #474747;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16pt;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.65em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your `appearance:none`...

It will reset your "view" of checkbox as you can read in any css docs. So your default style is `none`. Browser doesn't know how it looks so for example add

```
input[type=checkbox]{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

and your style is not empty anymore.

Comment: Worked. Used following guide for own style: https://boolie.org/css-checkbox-styling/

Comment: cool. I think you should accept some answer to close the question, because now its showing as unresolved. Greetings

Answer (score 0):

CSS "appearance: none;" on input will make Checkboxes invisible. So this block will make checkboxes disappear but will only remove browser default style on normal text inputs or removes the arrow on select inputs:

```
input, select, textarea {
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
}
```

This is often done to disable the default styles. Apparently, no new styles have been defined for checkboxes so they are invisible.